# Changing Default Storage Engine Amazon RDS MariaDB

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb, myisam, rds

I have hundreds of large tables that I have migrated to RDS MariaDB from my MySQL DB (using the amazon migration service). All of the storage engines went from MyISAM to InnoDB. This has a catastrophic impact on performance.

In short, I'm looking to change the default storage engine to MyISAM and then re-migrate all of the tables over. I'm open to any other ideas about how to do this as well (such as using some sort of setting in the migration tool). I don't really want to create a script to change them over, because this means I'll need to do this every time I import data.

I've tried changing the ParameterGroup default_storage_engine, but when I go into the ParameterGroup for the instance I am running, the default storage engine shows up as read-only.[image: AWS Console Screenshot]

I've tried creating a new parametergroup as well, and the same happens. The value shows up as "modifiable: false".

Any help much appreciated. I've looked around at other answers, but I don't think modifying my.cnf is relevant to RDS. If it is, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently RDS doesn't allow you to change that parameter.

You can change each of your tables to MyISAM, one at a time:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

You can get a list of your tables you need to change:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE ENGINE='InnoDB';
```

For future tables, don't rely on the default engine. Create tables with the engine named explicitly in the CREATE TABLE statement.

I would caution you, however: MyISAM is being phased out by MySQL. It doesn't support concurrent writes, row-level locking, transactions, or atomic changes. InnoDB is shown over and over to be superior in performance, to MyISAM, except in a vanishingly few cases:

- `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable;` because MyISAM keeps this stat built into each table. This is admittedly the big weakness of InnoDB or any MVCC architecture.
- Table-scans. But you shouldn't be doing table-scans anyway, you should be doing index lookups. An optimized query against InnoDB will generally be much better for performance than a table-scan against MyISAM.

I would encourage you to figure out your query optimization and stick with InnoDB.

Comment: MyISAM also is also strongly discouraged by the RDS docs, since it appears to be fundamentally incompatible with the mechanisms underlying RDS snapshot backups and point-in-time recovery -- these appear to be based at least in part on InnoDB's ability to recover from the crash-like state that results when MySQL first wakes up after being restored from a backup created by a disk snapshot. This wouldn't be handled well by MyISAM tables.  (Anecdotal observations suggest that point in time and snapshot restorations in RDS appear to go through crash recovery on startup.)

Answer (score 0):

A common performance problem when suddenly switching to InnoDB has to do with "transactions".

Probably what happened is that every query became its own transaction because `autocommit = ON`.  (Don't turn it `OFF`, that will lead to worse problems.)  You need to understand transactions, at least enough to combine statements together in blocks like

```
BEGIN;
multiple statements, usually more than one, but not a huge number
COMMIT;
```

This (in many cases) will regain a bunch of the lost performance.

More discussion on conversion is [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb) .